# Direct product isomorphism in Galois Theory's proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, normal-subgroups

During a Galois Theory lecture, we proved that:

> Let $K$ field, $f=gh \in K[x]$ separable polynomial and $F, B, C$ splitting fields respectively of $f, g, h$ over $K$, if $B \cap C=K$ then
> $$
> \operatorname{Gal}\left({F} / K\right) \cong \operatorname{Gal}\left({B} / K\right) \times \operatorname{Gal}\left(C/K\right)
> $$

In the proof we state that
$$\frac{\operatorname{Gal}(F / B) \times \operatorname{Gal}\left({F} / C\right)}{\operatorname{Gal}(F / B)} \cong \operatorname{Gal}(F / C)$$
and that it "follows from the Third isomorphism theorem", I can't see why. And I was wonderind if it follows from this

> Let $G$ group, $H, K, N \unlhd G$ such that $G = H \times K$, then
> $$\frac{G}{N} = \frac{H \times K}{N} \simeq \frac{H}{N \cap H} \times \frac{K}{N \cap K}$$

- Why I think it's true:

$$N \unlhd G = H \times K$$
$$N \unlhd G \implies N \cap H \unlhd H, \ N \cap K \unlhd K$$

- What I'm not sure about:

If $\frac{H}{N \cap H} \times \frac{K}{N \cap K}$ is a direct product... Are they even a normal subgroup of something? (Like normal subgroups of $\frac{G}{something}$)

- Notes:

When I write "$\times$" I mean direct product.

I don't need the entire proof of the statement, just a clarification of that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First. Note that the isomorphism you have quoted is actually of the form
$$\frac{NK}{N}\cong K$$
where $N$ and $K$ are normal and satisfy $N\cap K=\{e\}$ (so that $NK\cong N\times K$). In particular, you are moding out by the first factor, not just some random normal subgroup.

This isomorphism is straightforward: define $f\colon NK\to K$ by $f(nk)=k$. Note that because $N\cap K=\{e\}$, elements of $NK$ can be written uniquely in the form $nk$ with $n\in N$ and $k\in K$, and because both $N$ and $K$ are normal, we know that $nk=kn$ for all $n\in N$ and $k\in K$; this implies $f$ is a (surjective) homomorphism with kernel $N$, as desired.

Second, you ask if the following holds:

> Let $G$ be a group, $N,H,K$ normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G=H\times K$; then $\frac{G}{N} \cong \frac{H}{H\cap N}\times \frac{K}{K\cap N}$.

The answer is no. Take $G=C_2\times C_2$ to be the Klein $4$-group, let $H=C_2\times\{e\}$, $H=\{e\}\times C_2$, and let $N=\{(e,e),(x,x)\}$ be the diagonal subgroup. Then $\frac{G}{N}\cong C_2$ has order $2$, but $H\cap N = K\cap N=\{e\}$, so your right hand side is just $H\times K$ which has order $4$.